# Xamarin won't build out of memory

Tags: android, xamarin

I get the following error, but when I increase the Max Heap Size, it doesn't have any effect.  I have gone up to 8G with no change.  Is there something else going on?

Suppression State
Error       java.lang.OutOfMemoryError. Consider increasing the value of $(JavaMaximumHeapSize). Java ran out of memory while executing 'java.exe -Xmx1G -jar "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\28.0.0-rc1\lib\dx.jar" --dex --no-strict --output obj\Debug\android\bin "C:\code\Droid\obj\Debug\android\bin\classes.zip" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v8.0\mono.android.jar" obj\Debug\lp\10\jl\bin\classes.jar obj\Debug\lp\11\jl\bin\classes.jar obj\Debug\lp\12\jl\bin\classes.jar obj\Debug\lp\13\jl\bin\classes.jar obj\Debug\lp\14\jl\bin\classes.jar obj\Debug\lp\15\jl\bin\classes.jar obj\Debug\lp\16\jl\bin\classes.jar obj\Debug\lp\17\jl\bin\classes.jar obj\Debug\lp\18\jl\bin\classes.jar obj\Debug\lp\19\jl\classes.jar obj\Debug\lp\20\jl\classes.jar obj\Debug\lp\21\jl\classes.jar obj\Debug\lp\22\jl\classes.jar obj\Debug\lp\3\jl\arch-core-common.jar obj\Debug\lp\4\jl\arch-lifecycle-common.jar obj\Debug\lp\5\jl\bin\classes.jar obj\Debug\lp\6\jl\bin\classes.jar obj\Debug\lp\8\jl\bin\classes.jar obj\Debug\lp\9\jl\bin\classes.jar'

Comment: `...-Xmx1G...` In the error, your Java Heap Size for builds is set to 1GB, are you setting the correct parameter?

Comment: Delete Bin and Obj folders.

Comment: @Woj That worked, put that as an answer and then I can mark it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete bin and object files. If you are using Mac i would recommend adding nice plugin:

[enter link description here](https://montemagno.com/xamarin-studio-obliterate-output-paths-binobj/)